# MySQL how to check if any value in a list of columns is NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select the entries in a mysql table where there are NULL values, to later do an update or a delete on them:

```
select * from table where q is NULL;
```

But I have a rather long list of them, in this case all with a given prefix called `pf_`, and I want to select the entries where any of the columns is NULL. Can I do something like this?

```
select * from table where ANYISNULL(pf_q,pf_w,pf_e,pf_r,pf_t,pf_y,pf_u,pf_i,
                                    pf_o,pf_p,pf_a,pf_s,pf_d,pf_f,pf_g,pf_h,
                                    pf_j,pf_k,pf_l);
```

Any ideas how to do this other than having a very long query with lots of ORs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should do this:

```
select * from table where concat(pf_q,pf_w,pf_e,pf_r,pf_t,pf_y,pf_u,pf_i,
                                pf_o,pf_p,pf_a,pf_s,pf_d,pf_f,pf_g,pf_h,
                                pf_j,pf_k,pf_l) is null;
```

If any of the values is null, [`concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) will return null.

Comment: That's some "outside-of-the-box" thinking right there. Nice work.

Comment: That's damn sexy, @Michael

Comment: I know I am late to the party on this, but brilliant! Just what I needed to solve a problem I am working on.